# sql server / entity framework. call store function from .net 3.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

There is some problem with call function

```
var query = _entities.CreateQuery<double?>(
String.Format("select [dbo].[udf_ExchangeCurrencyRatesGetValue] ({0},{1},{2},{3})", "'bid'", activeScenario.Scenario_id, product.ID, pair.Instr_id));

var bidValue =  query.Execute(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges).GetEnumerator().Current;
```

activeScenario.Scenario_id, product.ID, pair.Instr_id - integer variables.

When query.Execute executed, fires Exception:

*Invalid query syntax., Near line 2, column 0.*

That query runs completely on .net 4:

```
var bidValue =DataAdapter.ModuleEntities.ExecuteStoreQuery<double?>(String.Format("select [dbo].[udf_ExchangeCurrencyRatesGetValue] ({0},{1},{2},{3})", "'bid'", ratesScenario.Scenario_id, product.ID, pair.Instr_id)).First();
```

Does anyone know how to run this code on .net 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call table-valued function in MS SQL via Entity Framework;
You can use this:

```
var retval = new List<MyClass>();
retval = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(String.Format(@"select * from dbo.myDatabaseFunction({0})", id)).ToList<MyClass>();
```

We have to say map type for ToList<> method and MyClass must be include all columns which return by function.